# i am not able to filter records with rxjs filter?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

In the `angular` project, i have `rxjs` `filter` through which i am not able to filter records. My function is here

```
public getOrders(type: string, filterObj = {}, otherParams = {}): Observable<{ name: string; qt: number }[]> {
   return this.http.get(apiUrl, { params: { filter: JSON.stringify(filterObj), ...otherParams},
   })
   .pipe(map((res: any) => res.payload))
   .pipe(filter((order: any) => order.name && /\S/.test(order.name)));
}
```

It's not filtering the records. It's not returning any values.

But if i do like this so it's working correctly.

```
public getOrders(type: string, filterObj = {}, otherParams = {}): Observable<{ name: string; qt: number }[]> {
   return this.http.get(apiUrl, { params: { filter: JSON.stringify(filterObj), ...otherParams},
   })
   .pipe(map((res: any) => res.payload.filter((order: any) => order.name && /\S/.test(order.name))))
}
```

what's going wrong here?

Comment: *In the angular project, i have rxjs filter that is not working the way it should.* Now that is a bold statement tbh

Comment: updated the statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there's a difference between [rxjs `filter`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/filter) and the [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

The rxjs `filter` is used to filter out observable emissions that you don't need - supposing that your source observable emits more than one value (which is not the case with `httpClient.get`)

The `Array.filter`, the one that you do need, in order to filter out some elements inside an array is a method that returns an array which contains the elements that correspond to your filter criteria. So in order to do this the right way, you could write something like this:

```
public getOrders(
  type: string,
  filterObj = {},
  otherParams = {}
): Observable<{ name: string; qt: number }[]> {
  return this.http
    .get(apiUrl, {
      params: { filter: JSON.stringify(filterObj), ...otherParams },
    })
    .pipe(
      map((res: any) => res.payload),
      map((orders) =>
        orders.filter((order: any) => order.name && /\S/.test(order.name))
      )
    );
}
```

Or simply omit the second `map` and do it the same way you did it the second time when it worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your payload is an `array` - no wonder it does not work as you would like it to work

What you essentialy do is

```
const arr:any = [];
if(arr.name){///whatever}
```

does that make sense? Rather not.

your `filter` works as it should work, your code is badly written as it should not be. Therfore as I wrote

> In the angular project, i have rxjs filter that is not working the way
> it should.

was a bold statement

Stop using `any` everywhere, start using typing system (the main reason behind TS) and you will not have such problems in the future